# Select an option value with multiple options

Tags: supersearch

I need to have a single option in a dropdown list that produces results from more than one value, like this:

```
<select name="length">
    <option value="">Any Length</option>
    <option value="3+4+5">3-5 Days</option>
    <option value="6+7+8+9">6-9 Days</option>
    <option value="10+11+12+13+14">10-14 Days</option>
</select>
```

For example, the first option works for 3, 4 and 5 days, but it also includes 13, 14 and 15.

I have tried numerous variations without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some code? What exactly does the drop down do, set a value? Which one, where? I'm a little confused on the details.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy display above. I have a directory with a series of entries that each have a certain length of time, i.e., 7 for 7 days. The option value is meant to combine groups of days in the search results such as all entries that have a length of 3,4 or 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can accomplish what you're looking to with a select field and SuperSearch. One solution would be to use two fields and the `from` and `to` modifiers:

https://solspace.com/expressionengine/super-search/docs/form/#customfield-from

https://solspace.com/expressionengine/super-search/docs/form/#customfield-to

If you really want to run with a select, you can work some front-end magic with jQuery. Stop the propagation of the form submittal, and get the value of the `length` select. Then set two hidden `input` fields with the `customefield-from` and `customefield-to` value you'd like (3-5, 6-9, etc..), and continue with the form submit.

It might still be possible; the documentation is your friend, dig in, I may have missed something.